# Add custom fields to show in wp query loop ? (gutenberg + kadence block)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have
-wordpres 6.2
-generatepress theme
-gutenberg editor[image]
-kadence plugin with 'latest post' plugin
-ACF (where I've created two custom fields: price and size)

I'm using POSTS block (from kadence) on mainpage. It shows list of post
picture, title and category. How to show two custom fields above title ?
(in the simpliest way)

I've tried many methods using functions.php and nothing :(